# How do i make my menu bar appear only when icon is scrolled over?

Tags: html, css, menubar

I am trying to make a menu bar like this one
http://www.finlandia.com/en
I am not sure how they are doing that i would imagine i has to do with a scroll over, but when i try it, the words still appear even when the menu bar is collapsed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<!-- SlideBars Meta-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<!-- END SlideBars Meta-->

<!-- This is the SlideBar CSS link-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/slidebars.min.css">
<link href="CSS/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- END SlideBar CSS link-->
</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top sb-slide" role="navigation" style="webkit-transform: translate(381px);">
    <a class="hidden-phone"><!-- Main navigation menu bar is apearing when desktop version is avalible-->
        <div class="main-nav">
            <div class="navicon-line-padding">
                <div class="navicon-line"></div>
                <div class="navicon-line"></div>
                <div class="navicon-line"></div>
            </div><!-- END navicon-line-padding-->
            <ul class="main-nav-li">
                <li>Home</li>
            </ul><!-- End Main-nav-li-->
        </div><!--End Main-nav-->
    </a><!-- End hidden-phone-->

    <a id="nav-open-btn" class="visible-phone" rel="track-event" data-ga-action="Mobile Menu" href="#">
        <div class="sb-toggle-left navbar-left">
            <div class="navicon-line"></div>
            <div class="navicon-line"></div>
            <div class="navicon-line"></div>
        </div>
    </a><!--END nav-open-btn-->



<!-- This Div is in place to make the MenuBar Work properly do not move-->
<div id="sb-site">
<p>

</p>

</div>
</nav>
<!-- END Sb-site Div-->

<!-- This is the SB-SlideBar Left Div-->
<div class="sb-slidebar sb-left sb-style-push sb-toggle-left">

    <nav>

      <ul class="sb-menu">

            <li class="SquirrelIcon">
                <a href="#"><img src="imgs/FurrySquirrelLogo2.png" width="300"  height="174" alt="Furry Squirrel Productions"></a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#" class="LinkItemMenu">Home</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </nav>

</div><!-- END sb-slidebar sb-left div-->

<!-- Start SlideBar JQuery-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">   </script>
<!-- END SlideBar Jquery-->

<!-- Start SlideBar JS-->

<script src="JS/slidebars.min.js">
</script>

<script>
  (function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.slidebars();
    });
  }) (jQuery);
</script>

<!-- END SlideBar JS-->

</body>
</html>
```

my CSS code:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.navicon-line {
background-color: #000;
height: 4px;
width: 24px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 1px;
}
.sb-toggle-left.navbar-left {
padding: 14px;
z-index: 1030;



top:
;
width: auto;
position: fixed;
}
.navbar.navbar-default.navbar-fixed-top.sb-slide {
position: fixed;
z-index: 1303;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}

.SquirrelIcon {
margin-top: 20%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
margin-left: 5%;
margin-right: 5%;
}
.sb-menu .SquirrelIcon a img {
height: auto;
max-width: 100%;
}
#sb-site p {
width: 300px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 43.125em) {
.visible-phone {
   display: inherit !important;
}

.hidden-phone {
  display: none !important;
}

}
.main-nav-li {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 1.5em;
color: #000;
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
}
.main-nav:hover {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
background-color: #0C0;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
.hidden-phone {
height: auto;
width: 100%;
}
.navicon-line-padding {
padding: 14px;
}
```

I am trying to make all of the items invisible when the user is not scrolled on. and visible when the user scrolls over the icon.

Comment: so basically you are talking about the parallax-scrolling? Or something else? Honestly I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve. Might want to explain a bit more or phrase differently so people can help you better

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am looking purely at the menu bar of that link. when the user scrolls over the hamburger style menu bar icon the menu bar appears and when the mouse hovers off of the menu bar it disappears to show the hamburger style menu bar icon again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Adam the author of Slidebars :)

The link you shared doesn't appear to be working, so I'll have to just take a guess at what your trying to achieve.

Theres a couple of issues with your markup. First you have your `#sb-site` container within your navbar, this needs to be outside. So your markup may look like this:

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar"></nav>
    <div id="sb-site"></div>
    <div class="sb-slidebar sb-left"></div>
</body>
```

It seems in a comment, you dont want the navbar to move. In that case, just remove the class `.sb-slide`, and the plugin wont animate the navbar :)

If your navbar is staying still, the hover effect should be quite easy to achieve. Slidebars has an API which you can use to control them. I have put together a JSFiddle to demonstrate this.

http://jsfiddle.net/7YzF4/

I hope this helps!

Thanks, Adam